# How do I release the Camera in Android (Xamarin app) when using MediaStore.ActionImageCapture to take pictures?

Tags: android, xamarin, camera, mediastore

I have an Android app that uses the camera to take a picture (wrote the code using the sample linked below), but whenever I quit the app, the Camera is not released properly, so subsequent attempts to immediately open the app after closing it fail (the app crashes). If I wait about 10 seconds then the Camera is released and I can reopen the app.

I tried Camera.release() but that method is not recognized. Any idea?

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/

Code:

```
private void TakeAPicture()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    _file = new File(_dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
    intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(_file));
    StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Comment: We are using the `Xam.Plugin.Media` plugin for camera and photo operations in a Xamarin.Forms app with iOS and Android packages. The camera is released properly on app exit, but there are certain sequences where app flow (redirect to login) causes a similar issue as you describe, so I'm going to follow your question and if we solve this, I'll update.

Comment: Thanks, I am using MVVMCross and not Xamarin.Forms, in case this information helps. In my other 2 projects (Windows Phone and iOS) I had to write code for each but didn't have any issues releasing the camera. In the case of Android I see that perhaps picking Xamarin's sample code is not the best alternative... perhaps I should use the more generic Camera class approach?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that what was missing was the release of my Bitmap object instance holding on to the captured image, not the Camera, since the call to the camera -which in this code sample is done via an Android Intent- apparently takes care of it.

So the solution is to simply set the Bitmap object to null on onDestroy().

Happy coding